# Scikit-learnのデータセットを読み込む方法を教えてください

Tags: python, scikit-learn

機械学習のサンプルコードをそのまま写しましたが、ファイルの読み込みができていなくて困っています。環境が違うことが原因なのでしょうか？花のがくの大きさや長さなどから花の種類を判定するプログラムの、データが入っているファイルが読み込めないです。

エラー

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'iris.csv'
```

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
```

Comment: iris.csv はPython のプログラムと同じフォルダに保存されていますか？

Comment: されていません。それのやり方が分からなくて困っています。

Comment: `iris.csv` を絶対パスで指定してみてください。

Comment: iris.csv はお使いのPCに保存（ダウンロード）済でしょうか？「機械学習のサンプルコードをそのまま写しました」であれば細かい操作についてもどこかに書いてありませんか？（書籍ではなくブログ等の記事の場合は割愛されているかもしれませんが）

Comment: 初心者なので用語が不正確かもしれませんが、scikit-learnというライブラリの中にあるデータセットのファイルを読み込みたいのですが、その操作については説明がなかったです。また、絶対パスを指定するというコメントに関しては絶対パスをどうやって調べればいいのかがわかりませんでした。

Comment: 「scikit-learnというライブラリの中にあるデータセットのファイルを読み込みたい」とのことですが、「pd.read_csv('iris.csv')」のコードだけでは出来ません。おそらく「機械学習のサンプルコード」が載っているものに説明があるはずなので確認されるのが良いと思います。もし質問のコード以外に何の説明もないものでしたらそちらを参考に今後の学習を進めるのは厳しいかと思います。1から説明があるものを参考にされた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: 「絶対パスを指定するというコメントに関しては絶対パスをどうやって調べればいいのかがわかりませんでした。」 例えば、`import sklearn.datasets.data as sk_data` と `import os.path` を実行しておいて、`iris_csv_path = os.path.join(sk_data.__path__[0], 'iris.csv')` とします。ただ、sklearn に含まれている `iris.csv` ファイルは内容の形式が一般的なものとは異なりますので、Pandas の `read_csv()` でそのまま読み込んでも期待している様なデータフレームにはならないでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> scikit-learnというライブラリの中にあるデータセットのファイルを読み込みたい

`load_iris()` に `as_frame` キーワードを指定するとよいかと思います。

```py
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

df = load_iris(as_frame=True)['frame']
print(df)

#      sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  target
# 0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2       0
# 1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2       0
# 2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2       0
# 3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2       0
# 4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2       0
# ..                 ...               ...                ...               ...     ...
#
# 145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3       2
# 146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9       2
# 147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0       2
# 148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3       2
# 149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8       2
# 
# [150 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: これでできました！回答に協力してくださった皆さんありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

その(何らかの)機械学習の資料に記されているはずではないかと思います
一応は, 以下のように可能なはず ([colab](https://colab.research.google.com/?hl=ja)で確認)

(この回答時点で scikit-learn は 1.2.2)

```py
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
# 1.2.2
```

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset = load_iris()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(iris_dataset.data, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
df
```

|  | sepal length (cm) | sepal width (cm) | petal length (cm) | petal width (cm) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5.1 | 3.5 | 1.4 | 0.2 |
| 1 | 4.9 | 3 | 1.4 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 4.7 | 3.2 | 1.3 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 4.6 | 3.1 | 1.5 | 0.2 |
| 4 | 5 | 3.6 | 1.4 | 0.2 |
| 5 | 5.4 | 3.9 | 1.7 | 0.4 |
| 6 | 4.6 | 3.4 | 1.4 | 0.3 |
| 7 | 5 | 3.4 | 1.5 | 0.2 |

(略)

---

(**update**)

#### pandas DataFrameを直接取り出す

[Scikit-Learn’s Transformers Now Output Pandas Dataframes!](https://ponder.io/scikit-learns-transformers-now-output-pandas-dataframes/) によると

- Part 1: What are transformers, and what about sklearn’s transformers implementation has changed?
- Part 2: How does enabling Pandas dataframe outputs change the user experience?
- Part 3: What does this change suggest about the trajectory of Pandas use in ML workflows?

の中で以下のように説明があります (機械翻訳)
(上記の colabのようなアクセスが出来ないなら, バージョン違いにより何かが異なるのかもしれません)

> まず、有名な Iris データセットを読み込みます。 この更新の前に、sklearn では Pandas データフレームをトランスフォーマーにフィードすることがすでに許可されていたため、以前でも `as_frame=True` を選択し、`.head()` で入力データを検査することができました。

示してあるコードは以下の通り。これは colabでも確認可能

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_iris(as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=0)

X_train.head()
```

Comment: こちらも試してみましたがうまく動きませんでした。回答本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: どのように動かなかったのでしょう？ エラーなどが出たなら記したほうがよいでしょう。また Colabで試しましたか？ `sklearn.datasets` が他と違う構造だとするなら, そのような情報は質問に記したほうがよいでしょう

Comment: ファイル自体は読み込めたのですが、targetのcolumnがなかったのでその先のプログラムが動かなかったです。説明不足ですみません

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(iris_dataset.data, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)` とする場合には `target` 情報が含まれません。(`target` は `iris_dataset.data` には含まれていませんし、`feature name` でもないからです)

Comment: @metropolis `target`カラムが必要かどうかは質問にないのでは？
ある程度のところまで 'DataFrame'が取得できるなら, その先は応用でできそうな気がします(分からなければ さらに質問が作られるかもしれないし)

Comment: 一般に頒布されている `iris.csv` には `target` カラムが存在します。(factor ではなく、実際には `setosa`, `versicolor`, `virginica` といった文字列になっていますが)